# Orbital Bombardment with Anti Matter

Tags: science-based, warfare, space, antimatter

I am trying to figure out the feasibility of using Anti Matter to bombard the surface of a planet from a position in space.

My gut feeling is that its not very feasible.  Wouldnt the Anti Matter react with the upper atmosphere and explode up there instead of on the surface?

Could the Anti Matter be successfully contained in something to deliver itself to the surface so it could explode there?  Or is dropping/firing such a container from space problematic as the container would heat up and vibrate whilst entering the atmosphere?

My guess is that if you were sufficiently advanced enough to have Anti Matter based weapons, they would only really be effective in space.  Using these weapons on a planets surface or anywhere surrounded with matter would have the risk of the weapon going off too early, or even worse, taking you out.

Comment: It really depends on the technology level accessible to the race using antimatter weapons. At current Earth level technology we are happy to create few molecules of antimatter and keep them stable for very short amount of time. So even imagining how such antimatter containment would look like is quite beyond my level of knowledge

Comment: Orbital Bombardment in itself is a very powerful weapon, combining that with AntiMatter would unnecessarily complicate your attack. What is it that you want to achieve? Crack the Shell, Blow off the atmosphere etc

Comment: @AEonAX surely orbital bombardment, like any kind of bombardment, is a method of delivering a weapon (such as a warhead), and not a weapon in itself?

Comment: @Jimmery: in orbital bombardment the 'warhead' is the kinetic energy of the bombardment itself: so essentially your delivery mechanism for anything from orbit is going to form part of the destructive power.

Comment: Unless your attacker has technology far in advance of ours, she will get far more bang for the buck if she uses conventional fusion weapons.  For the cost of a single 1 MT anti-matter warhead she can probably build thousands of devices on the scale of the Tsar Bomba.

Comment: @EvilSnack this is something I was saving for another question - which would be the most effective form of bombardment for a technologically advanced race

Comment: Just use big rocks, the damage will be immense anyway, and its very simple and reliable. Fly a mission to a nearby asteroid, capture it with a claw, and tow it into a lunar holding orbit... hmm, something sounds familiar...

Comment: @Innovine: Big rocks aren't that cost effective. You'd be better off coating a slug of iron with heatproof ceramic plates and slamming that into the planet. Cheaper, easier to aim, delivers more kinetic energy to the target rather than the atmosphere *and* you can fine tune the payload size for tactical bombardment if necessary. Not that I've ever had reason to think about the finer points of orbital bombardment... Nosiree....

Comment: Just use them as an extension of relativisitic kinetic weapons: Shooting them with .999999999c will not give them any time to react with the athmosphere

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Pretty sure anything moving that fast doesn't need to be made of antimatter to [crack the surface of the earth like an egg.](https://what-if.xkcd.com/20/)

Comment: @JoeBloggs: Sure, but did that ever stop anyone from doing it? We have fission boost nuclear weapons. Also antimatter weapons have a reaction rate problem as they blow matter away, surely launching them into the mantle will mitigate that...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: My point is that if you've got the capability to accelerate anything to those kinds of speeds then you don't need it to be antimatter: The kinetic energy held by such a projectile will be enough to make the antimatter annihilation of secondary concern. E=.5MV^2 applies here, which means at those speeds a gram of normal matter is carrying 11 megatonnes of kinetic energy. If it were antimatter you'd have an extra 0.043 megatonnes... It's not worth the hassle, really.

Comment: I imagine the ma n concern will be the shape of the charge. If it's just a sphere it will burn pretty slowly, as the annihilation at the surface will push matter away.

Comment: Check [Nemesis Games](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/22886612-nemesis-games) It has got dozen lengths tungsten accelerated to one hundred and fifty kilometers per second. It also has got rocks painted with Stealth Paint used as Kinetic Impactors.

Comment: I seem to recall an incident in EE "Doc" Smith's Lensmen series where an anti planet was kicked out of a wormhole right next to an enemy controlled world. His work pre-dated our current theories about anti-matter so he went a little ott in terms of how much he used.

Comment: @JosephRogers it wasn't exactly his ideas about antimatter that were off; to fully annihilate the planet they *would* have needed an antiplanet.  He just didn't account for how easy it is to destroy all hope of life on the thing without annihilating the whole thing.  That being said, given the varieties of lifeforms involved in that series, and especially given the true nature of Boskone (not that it was fully known at that point) total mass-energy conversion might very well be the only way to be sure.

Comment: My back-of-envelope calculations are that if you are in orbit, and wish to put one MT of boom on target, you need either a conventional 1 MT device, 23 grams of anti-matter, or a sphere of iron 25 meters across.  Of these three, the problems associated with the fusion device are mostly solved, whereas the problems with 60 kiloton hunks of iron, or 23 gram pieces of antimatter, are far from solved.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Lets take a look at destructive power.**

Matter-antimatter annihilation yields all of the available resting energy of both the antimatter and the matter it's annihilating. This may be more than you expect. In fact it's at least 43 kilotons per gram. The kinetic energy of the impactor is nothing compared to that. Since your aliens are looking at weaponising this stuff then I'm going to guess they have the capacity to make and handle a lot of it.

So lets assume (for fun) that our aliens are throwing around munitions on the same order of size as a small naval shell, say 500 kg. Each kg is 43 Megatons. You've lobbed enough antimatter into the atmosphere to theoretically yield 21.5 *GIGA*tons. The Tsar Bomba, largest nuclear bomb ever detonated, was only 57 megatons (1.3 kg), and that had a mushroom cloud that reached above the stratosphere and an 8 kilometre wide fireball. Tsar Bomba's fireball was prevented from reaching the ground by the shockwave it produced (it essentially blew itself back into the sky), but that same shockwave entirely levelled a town 55 km from the blast zone and caused third degree burns at 100km.

**So: Do you need containment?**

Not really. If you can make enough of this to be viable for use in warfare then you can just aim for the planet and hit go.

As soon as the antimatter hits the atmosphere (which it will be doing really early on, even if the atmosphere is thin) it's basically going to turn into a rocket engine trying to power it's way back up to the stars by blasting all the normal matter below it out of the way. BUT! Unless you skim the shot off the atmosphere then it shouldn't be able to do that until it gets pretty far through the atmosphere. Most of the matter in the atmosphere is concentrated in a layer about 15-18km thick. Remember how big Tsar Bomba was? Even if your munition doesn't get anywhere near the ground it's still going to devastate it.

The advantage to antimatter weapons is that they'll keep exploding until they're completely consumed: Exploding high up in the atmosphere is still exploding: still creating a huge shockwave, and still creating huge problems for everyone below (like blinding people). Essentially you're going to have a Tsar Bomba going off *continuously* until all the antimatter is used up.

If it doesn't have sufficient time to turn itself around and leave the atmosphere before utterly fragmenting then it's just going to turn into a raging fireball, and it's likely that fragments of it will in fact be propelled downwards by air hitting the projectile from above (as air does have a bad habit of enveloping things), causing the 'explosion' to descend even closer to the ground.

And this is assuming that you didn't already give it enough power to hit the ground: If you've launched it downwards on a steep orbital re-entry path then it will be going fast enough that the outer layers of antimatter won't be able to create enough of a 'burn' to generate any meaningful thrust (due to the fact that it's annihilating it's reaction mass and blasting any further fuel away in an undirected fashion). It will, however, leave a wake of unprecedented destruction behind it on it's way to the ground, whereupon it's going to be surrounded on all sides by matter it can annihilate with.

Other answers have addressed that containment is possible. I'm just going to go out on a limb and say if you've got the ability to make any reasonable amount of antimatter then it *really* isn't necessary.

Comment: I don't think this is plausible, First hits with regular matter will produce heat until the shell (I assume you put into shell shape) becomes plasma scattering them. Since the heating occurs from the bottom, it will scatter antimatter outwards. Some of it will continue hitting the air around, scorching the upper atmosphere, some (tiny amount) will reach up to your space craft and do damage. Although it will probably end the life on the ground due to extreme X-Ray radiation, I don't believe it will ever touch the ground.

Comment: Containment could allow for it to be more devastating though. If the "shell" survives to impact the planet's surface, then the reaction is *starting* at the surface, and could significantly damage the planet's crust. In addition to all the direct kinetic and thermal damage from matter-antimatter annihilations, such a disturbance in the crust could cause planetwide earthquakes and volcanic eruptions (assuming a molten core).

Comment: @DoktorJ: It certainly could, but as others had already said that I thought I'd focus on why you wouldn't need it if you wanted to avoid complexity and could make enough of it.

Comment: @CemKalyoncu: The shell will indeed become plasma and start to scatter, but so will the matter underneath it, and the matter underneath that, and the shell will rapidly turn into either a 'spike' of antimatter plasma slamming downwards at 30km/s like a supremely effective [EFP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_formed_penetrator) or it'll leave a trail of fire brighter than the sun with a thermal shockwave that would make Tsar Bomba look like a firecracker. It doesn't have to reach the ground to devastate, is my point.

Comment: this answer openned my eyes to the realities of anti matter orbital bombardment - even without containment, given enough of a push the warhead would cause significant damage to a planet - and the imagery of an immense exploding fireball descending onto a planets surface is also pretty damn awesome - have a tick

Comment: @Jimmery: …and the significant damage is the goal of a weapon, not hitting the surface. Note that nuclear weapons are usually ignited in the atmosphere, not at the surface, because it will cause a *higher* devastation.

Answer (score 21):

### Of course it's plausible.

The only thing that's slightly more out there in the realm of science-fiction is where they got the antimatter.

---

As you know antimatter is identical to ordinary matter in every way except that the particles it is made of have an opposite charge.
This means by manipulating magnetic/electric fields it can be effectively contained within a space surrounded by a vacuum because the antimatter particles get repelled to the center of the canister.

Now as you also know, so far we've only been able to successfully contain antimatter for a very short time (about 16 minutes). To be clear though this is not because longer containment is physically impossible, but rather because how to do so properly is a partially unsolved problem of engineering. Importantly we are [working on this issue](http://gizmodo.com/5765109/work-begins-on-worlds-largest-antimatter-containment-unit) and many believe we are close to solving it. And honestly, if your people can somehow find or create significant quantities of antimatter (enough for a bomb) then they've already solved it.

---

So what do you do now that you've got some contained antimatter? Well, just launch it from orbit. The electromagnetic field will persist within the atmosphere but will certainly fail when what generates it gets destroyed on impact. When that happens all the antimatter is free to interact with normal matter and... boom. You get a very, very big explosion.

Comment: thanks for the great comment - you have me now thinking, could a planet deploy something like EMPs to disrupt the magnetic/electric containment fields and thus trigger the antimatter weapons early (before they hit the surface)?

Comment: Oh that's a really easy fix, just build it with a faraday cage on the exterior. So you have a 3 layer system: Faraday, matter seperation shell, matter vacuum containing the antimatter.

Comment: dont faraday cages need to be earthed? how would you earth the kind of anti matter weapon we are talking about whilst it was dropping from space and through the atmosphere of a planet?

Comment: No, the EM blast simply laps around the faraday cage, gradually losing heat until it is no longer effective. It has never been necessary to ground faraday cages for the purpose of blocking electromagnetic fields.

Comment: Note that "dropping it from orbit" really needs to be launching it from orbit with some velocity, or giving the canister some thrust of its own. If you just let it go in orbit, it will keep orbiting with your spacecraft until you do something about it. (luckily you are in space so you don't need to worry too much about it prematurely annihilating)

Comment: @mao47 & Jimmery Good catch, I was going for the figurative sense of drop as in: "drop off the package", but I suppose in response to such a question I should have been more technical. Edited for clarity.

Comment: I was 2 days ago in the "antimatter factory" at CERN. you can only trap antimatter for about 1000~ seconds. But to *bombard* a planet you do not need to trap it! The problems at CERN come from being able to have antimatter in vacuum in very low energy states. You want to kill a planet, you do not need to even store antimatter. You can have a cannon that *creates* antimatter at high energies and these are focused in a direction. That would suffice.

Comment: Antimatter is *not* just matter with electrical charges reversed, but the subtleties might not be important in your story. See Greg Bear's *Anvil of Stars* for a planetary defense system that makes creative use of antimatter.

Comment: Is antimatter sort of stable? As in, could you 'launch' a canister on a 10 year orbital trajectory, and reasonably expect most of it to arrive? So you don't actually need to contain it, because it's not actually anywhere near your (not antimatter) ship.

Comment: @Sobrique ...No the canister (being made presumingly out of ordinary matter) would interact with the antimatter inside and explode. And anyways what I say in my response still stands. To collect and store all this antimatter you already need to know how to contain it.

Comment: @Sobrique: Even if the canister isn't made of matter and you've fashioned a shell out of an anti-metal then you've still got to be careful about interstellar dust. Even a nanogram of matter touching your projectile will yield an explosive force on the order of a kilo of TNT going off, which should be more than enough to shatter the projectile. Not an issue if you're firing at short range but really, really important if you're aiming for anything longer.

Answer (score 6):

Antiprotons can be trapped in electromagnetic field. Since your bombs will be quite small, with the right materials, atmospheric entry of small shells will be possible. Find a way to trigger bombs when they hit the surface, and you will be done. That is easier than regular shells, once electromagnetic field is gone, antimatter will eat through the outer shell.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your initial description, it sounds like you are sending "naked" antimatter" to the planet, and yes, it will interact in the upper atmosphere.

Of course, this isn't going to be much of a help to the people below, positrons will interact with electrons releasing gamma rays at a distinct 512 KEv energy (anyone outside the battle zone picking up the signature will have no doubt at all what just happened), while anti protons will interact with protons releasing a blast of high energy subatomic particles. As you can see in the diagram of a theoretical antimatter rocket, this stew of pions and other charged particles breaks down in time to other particles as well as releasing gamma radiation.

[image]

*Antimatter reaction*

So the surface would be struck with a blaze of high energy radiation, followed shortly by the shockwave created by the atmosphere heating by the radiation release.

This would also affect everyone in space, since the radiation release would be spherical. Satellites and spacecraft in orbit would be irradiated by the high energy gamma rays and particles as well, which might even put the launching spacecraft in danger.

The best way to overcome these issues would be to enclose the antimatter in a containment trap which is programmed or designed to disintegrate at low altitude or on the ground, putting the energy right on the target where you want it to go.

Comment: Good point about blowback radiation!

Comment: Not to mention, the containment trap conveniently allows for the atmosphere now above the reaction to contain the it and (to a limited extent at least) dampen radiation.

Comment: this is a fantastic answer - I wish I could award the tick to more than one answer - thanks for the insight into the radiation resulting from a anti matter explosion

Answer (score 1):

As you have already commented the most effective way would be the ion trap. The two most common types of ion trap are the Penning trap and the Paul trap. A possible alternative could be the use of Optical tweezers, but this method can not contain the antimatter for a long time.

Also you have to take into account that there are different types of antimatter, you cannot define everything with the term antimatter and expect to treat it equally. Neutral antimatter is a different type of antimatter, which is not affected in the same way by ionic traps. **Last but not least, you have to keep in mind that it is not yet known how antimatter is affected by gravity and that could be a big problem for your bomb.**

Comment: As far as i am aware it is completely known how antimatter is affected by gravity; as in the same as normal matter. Antimatter just means particles with opposite electrical charge (electron+ = positron), all other properties being identical

Comment: Sorry but this is not true, if antiparticles or antimatter move in the opposite direction to ordinary matter (for the opposite electrical charge) in a gravitational field, the Principle of equivalence and with it to the general theory of relativity would be overturned.

Comment: We now know that gravity affects antimatter, but we do not know how it affects. For more information look for experiments carried out on the CERN.

Comment: To quote [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_interaction_of_antimatter): "The gravitational interaction of antimatter with matter or antimatter has not been conclusively observed by physicists. While the consensus among physicists is that gravity will attract both matter and antimatter at the same rate that matter attracts matter, there is a strong desire to confirm this experimentally."

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want your bombardment to accomplish.

Can you technobabble up an explanation for delivering antimatter from space to a planet's surface? Sure, that's just *Star Trek*'s photon torpedoes. It's likely to be very unpleasant for any inhabitants. and will scar up the surface.

Can you fire raw antimatter directly at the planet? Sure. It will react with the atmosphere in spectacular ways, and the fallout will be unpleasant for any inhabitants, but the surface may not be strongly affected (depends how much antimatter you use).

Can you fire raw antimatter at relativistic speeds so it makes it down to the surface? Sure, probably. You must really hate those guys. I don't even know how to estimate what that might do, but it will be unpleasant for any inhabitants and probably scar up the surface (depending how relativistic the speeds are).

Can you use your antimatter in an engine to just drop rocks on the surface? Sure, anything massive enough to survive reentry has some nasty bombardment characteristics ([Heinlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Moon_Is_a_Harsh_Mistress) overestimated, but [Pournelle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_bombardment) didn't). Following the theme, it will be unpleasant for any inhabitants, and probably scar up the surface.

In general though, you aren't going to achieve any non-exterminatory objective with antimatter. [Figure out what you're trying to do, and do that](https://www.clausewitz.com/readings/OnWar1873/BK1ch01.html#a) instead of focusing on the loudest toys.

Comment: Relativistic antimatter is redundant.  At 86% the speed of light, the kinetic energy of the projectile is equal to its mass energy.  Get it going faster, and the little bit of "bang" from being made of antimatter will be dwarfed by the big "bang" of the impact.

Comment: @Mark, the question wasn't size of the bang, but whether you can make the bang occur on the surface. Aside from that constraint, I agree: the "relativistic" part rapidly gets more exciting than the "antimatter" part.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem with an anti-matter kinetic energy weapon is that it will act exactly like a meteor.  You surely have seen the wonderful sights we have when we get meteor showers like the Leonids?

Unless the anti-matter is protected by a containment field which fails automatically when it reaches the surface, you are going to have your anti-matter KEW disintegrating when it hits every matter atom in its path on its route to the surface.  When enough matter particles interact with your anti-matter weapon, it's going to disintegrate.  If it's a large enough chunk of the local asteroid belt, it's going to have a worldwide killing effect.

One possibility is that the spaceship and crew are matter and the planet is anti-matter.  Nobody thought to check that possibility, so you get disastrous gamma radiation affecting both the planet and spaceship.

Sending down an exploratory vessel, perhaps with a diplomat or two, and having it disintegrate in the atmosphere of an anti-matter (to them) planet is not the best way to start diplomatic negotiations.  The planet may think it was a weapon.  The spaceship knows it was an accident but has no way to prove it.  Voila!  Instant interstellar war.  Any linguistic team would probably include scientists -- physicists, chemists, mathematicians, and other natural sciences -- since that would be the easiest way to establish common words.  The properties of carbon and oxygen don't change from one world to another.  But if the best diplomats and scientists you have with you have just been killed in this matter-anti-matter, you have a major problem.